# Electron travando quando abre mais de um aplicativo

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Estou passando por um pequeno probleminha :c

Sempre quando eu abro mais de um aplicativo Electron e ele começa a carregar uma nova janela principal para o usuário começar a usar o aplicativo, todo o sistema operacional fica extremamente lento por alguns segundos até a página ser completamente carregada.

Isso acontece apenas quando abre mais de um aplicativo Electron.
No meu caso, estou usando o Windows 10.

**Atualização da pergunta**

Misteriosamente outros aplicativos que rodam Electron como por exemplo o Discord, não fazem esse probleminha acontecer.

Isso acontece apenas entre os meus aplicativos desenvolvidos no Electron.

**Atualização 2**

Módulos usados no preload:

```
const { remote, ipcRenderer, shell } = require('electron');
const Tray = remote.Tray;
const Menu = remote.Menu;
const app = remote.app;
const dialog = remote.dialog;

const download = require('./download');
const exec = require('child_process').execFile;
const empty = require('empty-folder');
const JSZip = require("jszip");
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const osLocale = require('os-locale');
const ioHook = require('iohook');
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
const md5 = require('md5');
const md5File = require('md5-file');

const config = require('../../config.json');
const package = require('../../package.json');
const languagelist = require('../_locales/list.json');

const appUserModelId2 = remote.getGlobal("appUserModelId2");
const isAsar = remote.getGlobal("isAsar");
const tinyDir = remote.getGlobal("tinyDir");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o problema sozinha. Era um conflito acontecendo quando o módulo ioHook era carregado por outro aplicativo.

Mesmo assim obrigada por quem tentou me ajudar.

Comment: Isso tem solução ou tiveste de remover o iohook?

Comment: eu ainda não sei como resolver esse conflito porque não achei nadinha dizendo em relação para resolver isso. :c

Vai ser muito difícil achar um substituto porque eu preciso de um modulo que detecte teclas de atalho sem precisar de substituir uma existente e funcione no computador de forma global. Era exatamente o que eu conseguia com o iohook.

Answer (score 0):

O Electron é muito pesado. O motivo disso é que ele utiliza o Google Chrome por debaixo dos panos, e o Chrome é um devorador voraz de memória, processamento e IO de disco.

Veja aqui algumas referências sobre isso:

- [Electron is flash for the desktop](https://josephg.com/blog/electron-is-flash-for-the-desktop/)
- [Electron considered harmful because it rides on Chromium](https://techsparx.com/nodejs/electron/electron-heavy-weight.html)

Comment: Desculpe, mas a resposta não encaixa bem com o que eu realmente queria perguntar. Fiz uma atualização na pergunta para melhorar a justificativa da pergunta.